# Can I put salat on a pause until I can fix my mental issues?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, medical

I am making no excuses when I say I cannot pray. It is due to mental issues way beyond my control and I cannot avoid making mistakes in my salat no matter what I do.  Even if I don't make mistakes my OCD tells me I'm praying wrong. I don't want solutions because I've tried everything, but I can't pray unless I spend literally 3 hours a day trying to do so with extreme amounts of mental pain to the point where I cry every time I try praying because of how much I fail, even if I don't make mistakes.  Like I said, my OCD is extreme.

Can I put salat on a pause until I can fix my mental issues?

Because I'm sure Allah would not want someone to go through this amount each day. when I say it's extreme, I mean it.  Like I said, in no way am I making any excuses, but I just want to know if I can stop praying even if it's temporarily to fix these issues.

Comment: This looks like a follow-up question to [OCD difficulties while praying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38423/17163).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I remember you asking a question like this, no?

Comment: I asked [Is mental health treatment sufficient to make permissible otherwise haram acts?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35988/17163); it's related but not the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, my dear brother / sister, I ask Allah to make it easy for you and to reward you for your effort and to accept it, ameen.

As you yourself know Allah has made the salah obligatory and there are only few excuses for it.
Before I answer your question though, I will first mention something very important. Shaytan will do every possible thing to tell you that you do something wrong or to bring you away from salaah. He is the one who refused to do sujood so his task is now to use all means to make us like him.

I ask Allah to protect us, ameen.

What I would advice you is to try your best to do the salah no matter what happens, but here is a good news for you:

> قَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ يَسِّرُوا وَلاَ تُعَسِّرُوا، وَسَكِّنُوا وَلاَ تُنَفِّرُوا ‏
>    Narrated Anas bin Malik: The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Make things easy for the people, and do not make it difficult for them, and make them calm (with glad tidings) and do not repulse (them ).
>   Sahih al-Bukhari 6125

What you can do is, do only the obligatory parts of Salah, and if shaytan should whisper you say:

> a'udhu billahi mina sh-shaytani ar-rajeem

and dry spit on your right 3 times, if you forget something in salaah, then persform sujood as sahw: you do additional 2 sujoods before you do the tasleem in the end of salah, if you forget those 2 sujoods before tasleem do them after

If you should not be sure if you prayed 1-2 rakah pray one more and continue salah normally and before saying tasleem do additional 2 sujoods.

Giving up on salah is no solution, just try your best t do it and Allah is Forgiving and Most merciful and Allah will reward you for your effort. Do the best you can, but do not give up, I am sure you are strong and do not let Shaytan win, you will succeed just ask Allah for help in shaa Allah.

I hope my answer will help you in shaa Allah and in case you need the evidence for my answer about sujood as sahw I will send it to you.

Comment: There are quite a few things that you should provide references for here: 1) what to do when Shaytan whispers, 2) doubt with regards to the number of *rak'ahs* , 3) "giving up on *Salaah* is no solution", 4) "do your best". You can use the [edit](https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/39201/edit) button to make amendments

Answer (score -2):

Those who are sick,under age and old age are forgiven by Allah and they no need to perform the Salat

Comment: Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the help center, and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I agree with this answer. God is Most Forgiving. Surely He understands what you are going thru and thus forgives you if you skip prayers. There is no more evidence needed than "God is Most Forgiving".

Comment: Your Prayers don't count but your actions are important